Can composing a pair of 3D rotations about skew axes lead to a rotation?
If we compose two 3D rotations about axes that intersect at a point, we get another
rotation about an axis through the same point. There is a good description of this
on this page.
If the two rotation axes are parallel, we can treat the problem
as effectively two-dimensional by projecting onto a plane perpendicular to
the axes. In this case,  composing the rotations will either give a rotation
about an axis parallel to the original axes or a translation by a vector
perpendicular to them.
This question is about the case where we compose two non-trivial rotations about
non-intersecting, non-parallel (skew) axes.
I think that, in general (if not always?), the composition of two such rotations
will lead to a 'screw' or 'twist' transformation link - which can be expressed as a rotation about some arbitrary
axis followed by a translation parallel to the axis.
I'm trying to figure out
whether it is possible that the composition leads to only a rotation, i.e.,
with no along-axis translation. In summary, I'm trying to answer the following:

Is it possible for the composition of two non-trivial rotations about
skew  axes to be expressed as a rotation about some other axis?
If   so, under what conditions?


Let  $M$ be a `pure' rotation, i.e., one about an axis through
the origin, and if we want to
make the direction $\hat{u}$ of the axis and the angle $\theta$ explicit, we can
write $M = M_{\hat{u}, \theta}$.
To get a rotation about an arbitrary axis that does not contain $O$ and
goes through some point, $p$,
we can translate, rotate, and
translate back:
$$
t_{p} M t_{-p}
$$
where $t_{p}$ represents a translation by vector $p$: $t_{p} (x)  = x + p$ (following
the notation of Artin).
For any transformation of the form $M t_{v}$, we have
$$
M t_{v} (x) = M ( x + v ) = M(x) + M(v) = t_{M(v)} ( M (x))
$$
so we can write $M t_{v} = t_{M(v)} M$.
This means that for the general rotation about $p$,
$$
t_{p} M t_{-p} =
t_{p} t_{- M(p)} M 
=
 t_{p - M(p)}  M
 =
 t_{q}  M 
$$ where $q = p - M(p)$.
So we can express a general rotation about an axis through an arbitrary
point as a pure rotation, $M$, followed by a translation, $t_{p - M(p)} = t_{q}$.
Let $M =  M_{\hat{u}, \theta}$.
$q$ is a non-zero vector because the rotation is non-trivial and $p$ lies on an axis
not containing $O$.
We also have $q \perp \hat{u}$,
because both $p$ and $M(p)$ are contained in a plain perpendicular to $\hat{u}$.
Turning it around, if we are given a transformation in the form
$t_{q} M_{\hat{u}, \theta}$ where $q \perp \hat{u}$,
I believe
we can solve for $p$ in the equation $p - M(p) = q$ so that the
transformation can be written as a general rotation $t_{p} M t_{-p}$.

Given two rotations $t_{q} M_{\hat{u}, \theta}$ and
$t_{r} N_{\hat{v}, \phi}$, with $q \perp \hat{u}$
and $r \perp \hat{v}$,
the composition can be written
$$
t_{r} N \; t_{q} M
=
t_{r} t_{N(q)} \; N  M
=
t_{r + N(q)} K
=
t_{v} K
$$
where  $ K = NM$ is a pure rotation
and   $v = r + N(q)$
If $K = K_{\hat{w}, \psi}$, we can calculate $\hat{w}$ from
the parameters of the input rotations
$\hat{u}$, $\theta$, $\hat{v}$, $\phi$, using some known
method, e.g., a quaternion-based formula.
For example, this answer
shows that $\hat{w}$ is parallel to $w'$ where
$$
w' =
\cos \frac{\theta}{2} \sin \frac{\phi}{2} v 
+
\cos \frac{\phi}{2} \sin \frac{\theta}{2} u
+ 
\sin \frac{\phi}{2} \sin \frac{\theta}{2} v \times u
$$
For the composition, $t_{v} K$ to be a rotation, we need to have
$v \perp \hat{w}$ or $v \perp w'$. We can therefore set up an equation
like $v \cdot w' = 0$ and try to use this establish a  condition
on the original rotations.
This feels hard to me and I wonder if there is a geometric intuition
that shows either that $v \cdot w' = 0$  is not solvable given the initial
assumptions or, if it is, what conditions this then sets on the original
rotations about skew axes.

Given the result, $t_v K$, of composing the rotations above, where
$K = K_{\hat{w}, \psi}$, in general, the vector $v$ in the translation
will have components parallel to and perpendicular to the axis direction
$\hat{w}$ of $K$. Writing $v = a + b$ where $a \parallel \hat{w}$ and
$b \perp \hat{w}$, the composed rotations can be written as
$$
t_v M = t_{a + b} M = t_a t_b M
$$
Given that $b \perp \hat{w}$, the last two terms, $t_b M$, can be viewed
as a rotation about some arbitrary axis parallel to $\hat{w}$.
The translation $t_a$ is in the direction of $\hat{w}$. This shows how
$t_v M$ can be viewed as a screw or twist transformation.
So, the question can be summarised as: What conditions, if any, can be placed on the input rotations so that we have $a=0$ in the result above?

I think your last paragraph sums up the argument well. There will be special cases where $a=0$ and you have only a rotation, but the general case is a screw transformation. It seems clear enough.

Exactly, I'm trying to figure out what condition(s) can be placed on the input rotations to lead to $a=0$, if it is indeed possible.

Yes, if you compose two (nontrivial) rotations in noncoplanar lines, the result is never a rotation. I will add a proof later on.

Thank you, Moishe.

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space equipped with an inner product. Every affine transformation $g$ of  $V$
has the form $A_g + c_g$, where $A_g$ is a linear transformation (the linear part of $g$) and $c_g\in V$ (the translational part of $g$),
meaning that for $v\in V$,
$$
g(v)= A_gv + c_g. 
$$
I will use the notation $F_g$ to denote the fixed-point set of $g$ in $V$: it is a certain affine subspace of $V$. If $V=\mathbb R^3$ and $g$ is a nontrivial rotation, then $F_g$ is called the axis of $g$.
Lemmata below are quite straightforward (you just need elementary geometry and linear algebra to prove these) and I omit their proofs.
Lemma 1. (1) An affine transformation $g$ has a fixed point in $V$ if and only if $c_g$ belongs to the image of $A_g-I$. (2) If $g$ is an isometry, i.e.
$A_g\in O(V)$ is an orthogonal transformation,   the image of $A_g-I$ is the orthogonal complement to $F_{A_g}$.
Lemma 2. Suppose that $V=\mathbb R^3$. Then every rotation $R$ in $V$ is a composition of two reflections, $R=T\circ S$. These reflections are not unique: The reflection $S$ can be chosen so that its fixed hyperplane passes through the given point in $V$. Same for $T$. Once $S$ is chosen, the other reflection is, of course, unique.
Lemma 3. An orientation-reversing linear isometry of $V=\mathbb R^3$ has a nonzero fixed vector in $V$ if and only if it is a reflection.
Lemma 4. Suppose that $S_1, S_2, S_3\in O(3)$ are reflections. Then their composition $S_3\circ S_2\circ S_1$ is a reflection if and only if the fixed hyperplanes $F_{S_1}, F_{S_2}, F_{S_3}$ contain a common line.
Now, we are ready to prove:
Theorem. Suppose that $R_1, R_2$ are nontrivial rotations in $V=\mathbb R^3$. If their composition is a rotation, then the axes $F_{R_1}, F_{R_2}$ of $R_1, R_2$ are coplanar (lie in the same affine plane).
Proof. First of all, it suffices to consider the case when $R_1$ is a linear rotation, i.e. $R_1\in SO(3)$ (fixes the origin $\mathbf 0$ in $V$). We represent these rotations as compositions of reflections:
$$
R_i=T_i\circ S_i, i=1, 2. 
$$
Thus, $S_1, T_1$ are linear (since they have to fix the origin). By Lemma 2, we can assume that $S_2$ is also linear. We start by considering an easy case:
Case 1: $S_2\circ T_1\circ S_1$ is a reflection, equivalently, the fixed planes of the reflections   $S_2, T_1, S_1$ pass through the same line, necessarily, the axis $A_{R_1}$ of the rotation $R_1$. However, the axis $F_{R_2}=F_{S_2}\cap F_{T_2}$ is also contained in the plane $F_{S_2}$, hence, the axes $F_{R_1}, F_{R_2}$ are coplanar, as claimed.
Now, consider the "generic case,"
Case 2:  $T:= S_2\circ T_1\circ S_1$ is not a reflection. By the assumption, the composition $g=T_2\circ T= (T_2\circ  S_2)\circ (T_1\circ S_1)$ is a rotation, it equals
$$
(A_{T_2} + v)\circ T= A_{T_2}\circ T + v
$$
for some vector $v\in V$. Since $T_2$ is a reflection, $v$ is orthogonal to the plane $F_{A_{T_2}}$; since $h=A_g=A_{T_2}\circ T \in SO(3)$ and $g$ is a rotation, we also have that $v$ is orthogonal to the axis $F_h$  of $h$. If $v=0$, we are done (since both rotations $R_1, R_2$ are linear). Assume that $v\ne 0$.
The vector $v$ is orthogonal to both 1-dimensional linear subspace $F_h$ and 2-dimensional linear subspace $F_{A_{T_2}}$. If $F_h$ is not contained in $F_{A_{T_2}}$, then find a basis $\{v_1, v_2\}$ in $F_{A_{T_2}}$ and a basis $\{v_3\}$ in $F_h$. Since $v_3\notin F_{A_{T_2}}=Span\{v_1, v_2\}$, the vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3\in V$ are linearly independent, hence, form a basis in $V$. But $v$ is orthogonal to all these basis vectors. Hence, $v$ is orthogonal to every vector in $V$, which is, of course, impossible as $v\ne 0$.  Thus, $F_h\subset F_{A_{T_2}}$.
But then both $h$ and $A_{T_2}$ have to fix (pointwise) the line $F_h$; hence, $A_{T_2}\circ h$ fixes the line $F_h$ as well. However,
$$
A_{T_2}\circ h= A_{T_2}\circ A_{T_2}\circ S_2\circ T_1\circ S_1= S_2\circ T_1\circ S_1=T. 
$$
It follows that $T$ fixes the line $F_h$ (pointwise). By Lemma 4, the $T:= S_2\circ T_1\circ S_1$ is a reflection, which is a contradiction. qed

Thanks again. Digesting when I get time away from work. Re lemma 2, can the last part be rephrased as: "Either reflection can be chosen so that its fixed hyperplane passes through any given point in $V$. Once plane for one reflection is chosen, the other becomes fixed."

"Once a plane..."

@PaulAljabar: sure.

Re lemma 3, let $g$ be a transformation obtained by reflecting in the following three planes in order: $x=1$, $x=y$, $z=0$. I think $g$ is an isometry with a non-zero fixed point, $(1,1,0)$, but is not a reflection?

I meant to also say that $g$ is orientation reversing.

@PaulAljabar: I meant a linear isometry, an element of $O(3)$.

I think I'm getting there. Please could you expand on case 2 of the theorem, specifically the part that says: "Assume that $v \ne 0$. Then $F_h$ and $F_{A_{T_2}}$ cannot span $V$ which means" that  one is a subset of the other.

@PaulAljabar: If they span $V$ then we have a nonzero vector orthogonal to every vector of $V$, which is impossible. But if a line and a plane do not span a 3-space, then the line is contained in the plane.

Here's another idea. The given rotation axes $A_1$ and $A_2$ lie in planes $P_1$ and $P_2$ that are parallel to each other. Let $P$ be the 2D subspace parallel to these, and consider the orthogonal projections in $P$ of transformed points.
When $A$ is an axis parallel to $P$, any rotation around $A$ appears in the $P$-projection as a (possibly zero) displacement perpendicular to the projection of $A$. Since we have two such axes that are not parallel to each other, the respective perpendicular directions (as unit vectors in $P$, say) are linearly independent, so the only way we can get a fixed point is if both displacements are zero, i.e. both rotations fix the point's $P$-projection.
However, if a nontrivial rotation around $A_1$ fixes the $P$-projection of a point $x$, it must simply reflect $x$ across $P_1$. Since $P_1$ and $P_2$ are distinct, a reflection across $P_1$ followed by a reflection across $P_2$ is a nontrivial translation. Therefore, the combined transformation has no fixed points.

It is unclear to me how to justify the statements you are making (apart from the first patagraph). Did you check the details?

I agree this is very handwavy as written. I'll try tightening it up.

I think that looking at it this way might also be used to show that the resulting transformation is not a translation.

On the 2nd thought, the claim "First, since the axes are not parallel, the two kinds of rotation move points in different directions in the P-projection" is simply wrong.

Hmm, the argument there is: The orbit of a point under rotations around one axis is a circle whose projection on $P$ is a line segment (since $P$ is parallel to the axis). If the line segments corresponding to the two axes are parallel, the axes must have parallel $P$-projections.

This is not an argument. Replace one rotation by its inverse: the direction will change to the opposite.

For a single rotation, a point and its image are in a plane orthogonal to the axis, as are all points on the segment between them. Projecting the segment onto a plane parallel to the axis would give a segment perpendicular to the projection of the axis, or a single point.  Is that in line with the argument, Karl?

That's right. I'll clarify the post.
